# MSMQ Get All Private Queues

Tags: c#-4.0, msmq

Is there any way to get all of the queues on MSMQ 5.0 using .NET 4.0? Cheers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.getprivatequeuesbymachine.aspx) method

Comment: Thanks, I did see that somewhere but for some reason wasn't working is now :) Cheers again.

Comment: There is no method like `GetPrivateQueueByLabel` ?