# How to retrieve names of all private MSMQ queues - efficiently?

Tags: .net, powershell, com, wmi, msmq

How can I retrieve the **names** of all of the private MSMQ queues on the local machine, without using `System.Messaging.MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(".")`? I'm using PowerShell so any solution using COM, WMI, or .NET is acceptable, although the latter is preferable.

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329038/msmq-get-all-private-queues) has a solution that returns all of the queue objects. I don't want the objects (it's too slow and a little flakey when there are *lots* of queues), I just want their names.

Comment: read this SO question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289464/the-number-of-messages-on-an-msmq-via-powershell . The Keith Hill Answer..

Comment: Thanks, @Christian. Unfortunately the PSCX cmdlets use `GetPrivateQueuesByMachine` under the hood which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

```
$obj = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawdata_MSMQ_MSMQQueue ##will return an Object[] array
$obj[0].name ## will return the 1st Queue Name
```

Also, you can do this to find out more methods / properties on this object -

```
$obj | Get-Member
```

**To List only private Qs, you may use this -**

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawdata_MSMQ_MSMQQueue |
    ?{$_.Name -match "private"} |
        %{$_.Name}
```

Comment: Thanks, @AngshumanAgarwal. It works, but it's too slow. It doesn't fulfill the efficiency requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Windows Server 2012 and Win8, PS has a Get-MsmqQueue command.  It is faster than the get-wmiobject method in my tests.

```
Measure-Command {
  $list = Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private | % {$_.QueueName}
}
Measure-Command {
  $list = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawdata_MSMQ_MSMQQueue | ?{$_.Name -match "private"} | %{$_.Name} 
}
```